# Filtrar leitura de emails a partir de uma data

Tags: java, email, javamail, imap

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código que realiza a leitura de e-mails da caixa de entrada.

```
try {
    email.conectar();
    javax.mail.Store store = email.getArquivoEmail();
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

    //Aqui gostaria de pegar apenas e-mails dos últimos 10 dias.
    for ( Message message : inbox.getMessages() ){
        System.out.println("Mensagem: " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Data: " + ElfabDateUtils.formatDateOnly(message.getReceivedDate()));
    }

} catch (MessagingException ex) {
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Porém este código faz a leitura de todos os e-mails que estão na caixa de entrada, existe alguma forma de adicionar um filtro para que a leitura seja feita a partir de uma data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema utilizado `javax.mail.search.SearchTerm` e substituindo `inbox.getMessages()` por `inbox.search(dataInicio)` conforme código abaixo.

```
    try {
        email.conectar();
        javax.mail.Store store = email.getArquivoEmail();
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        SearchTerm dataInicio = new ReceivedDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GT, ElfabDateUtils.alterarDias(new Date(), -10));

        for ( Message message : inbox.search(dataInicio) ){
            System.out.println("Mensagem: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Data: " + message.getReceivedDate());
        }

    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Referência: [Link SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870045/java-imap-fetch-messages-since-a-date)